# Sharepoint Timer Job to Consume a REST Web Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Basically looking for some advice on how to create a Sharepoint 2010 Timer Job that will go and consume a REST web service, receive the response as XML and per element returned create a new list item in a Sharepoint List.

**Additional Information:**

Just to test the connection I have created a REST data source which works fine and returns all the data into a test aspx page.  I now want to be able to use the same connection to return the data in a Timer Job.  I have got the Timer job set-up but just not clear how I go about calling the API from within it.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please add additional information like this to your question instead of a comment. There should be a "edit" link above this comment section, that allows you to revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

Querying a rest datasource from a timer job would work in exactly the same way as querying a rest datasource from any .NET app. The only gotcha is that you probably dont want to store the config in an app.config file.

Instead look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx which shows how to call WCF entirely from code.